# Show the Set is Measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a part of a larger problem... but I am a little stuck on this little piece. I guess I am rusty on the stuff I learned last semester.

**Problem:**

$g$ is a monotonic increasing absolutely continuous function on $[a,b]$ with $g(a)=c, g(b)=d$.

$H=\{x : g'(x) \neq 0\}$

If $E$ is a measurable subset of $[c,d]$ then show that $F=g^{-1}(E)\cap H$ is measurable.

**My thinking:**

$g$ is monotone increasing as well as continuous, so it is a measurable function. Then $g^{-1}$ is also measurable? I know that this is not true in general. But I was thinking it is true for an absolutely continuous function. Then $g^{-1}(E)$ is measurable.

If $g$ is a measurable function then its derivative is measurable.
$H=\{x : g'(x) \neq 0\} \implies H^c=\{x : g'(x) > 0\}\cup\{x : g'(x) < 0\}$
So, $H^c$ is a union of measurable sets, and therefore it is measurable. The complement of a measurable set is measurable, so then $H$ itself is measurable.

The intersection of two measurable sets is measurable, so the result follows.

Comment: An absolutely continuous function need not be differentiable at every point; also, it is not given that $g$ has  an inverse. Hence you arguments need modifications.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. As I said, this is a smaller part of a bigger problem. I have a proof that a strictly increasing function that is defined on an interval has a continuous inverse. Additionally, if a function defined on an interval is non-decreasing, then it's derivative exists a.e.